# accessibility not working on disabled button

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, accessibility

need some help related to `accessibility`, facing some issue

I have one `button` `(Add To Cart)` in my page, it gets `disabled` once we add product to the cart
the button is not getting `focus` when we `press (tab key)` for accessibility

I have tried by adding the `aria-disbaled=true` still not working

any suggestion/solution for this one would help

Comment: Disabled means it won't get focus. If you still want it to get focus you should not disable it. Why do you think this is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `disabled` attribute entirely prevents the button from receiving focus (or receiving/triggering any events).

If you still want the button to receive focus then you will need to avoid using the `disabled` attribute and instead prevent the buttons functionality programmatically in your JS code when the conditions are met to do so; i.e. there is already an instance of the current product in the user's cart.

Comment: Thanks for this one, but do you have any other way because its gonna take time by removing the disable on the button

Comment: No, as the disable button has the effects I mentioned in the first paragraph.

Comment: No problem, glad to help